# Defining a Function for Any Column in a DF

Tags: python, pandas, function

In my example, I'd like to blank out "C" and "D" in Column1 as that corresponds to "Erase" in Column2. I'm trying to make this extensible to any future columns that I could use alternatively to Column1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {  'Column1': ["A","B","C","D","E"],
        'Column2': ["Keep","Keep","Erase","Erase","Keep"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Column1','Column2'])



def func(any_column):
    df[any_column][df['Column2'].isin(['Erase'])] = ""
    return any_column

df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].map(func)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop through your DF could work:
You can add the new columns in your Future_columns variable or find all the columns in your DF.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {  'Column1': ["A","B","C","D","E"],
        'Column2': ["Keep","Keep","Erase","Erase","Keep"],
        'Column3': ["A","C","D","F","E"] #Added DF
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3'])
```

Utilizing numpy to create a "If variable equal x then output Y else Z

```
import numpy as np
Future_columns=['Column1','Column3']
for x in range(len(Future_columns)):
    df['%s' %(Future_columns[x])]=np.where(df.Column2=="Erase","",df['%s' %(Future_columns[x])]) 
    df.head()
```

Or automate that piece of code, excluding 'Column1' using the list of column headers:

```
import numpy as np
all_columns=list(df)
all_columns.remove('Column2')
future_columns=all_columns

for x in range(len(Future_columns)):
    df['%s' %(Future_columns[x])]=np.where(df.Column2=="Erase","",df['%s' %(Future_columns[x])]) 
    df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df.Column1 = df.Column1.where(df.Column2 != 'Erase', None)
```

Comment: This isn't extensible per my requirement--Column1 could be Column40593.

Comment: use a function and the string accessor?